# SceneKit Swift - just play dae scene? Just getting white screen?

Tags: swift, 3d, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

Ok, I have created an animated scene (.dae) in Blender and exported it into Xcode. I followed a tutorial for that and already made a camera in Blender, etc.

In the SceneKit editor, I can click play on bottom and it plays my animation, that's great. I had read that you can just set your scene view scene and it should all play out from your camera, automatically.

My problem is I cant even see my objects, much less my animation. I just have white screen, despite evening setting background to a color then to an image. My editor structure:

[image]

where camera was previously in Armature but I moved it out to see. The scene is not nil I checked, this is how I add my scene to my scene view:

```
@IBOutlet var sceneView: SCNView!
    var scene: SCNScene!
    let str = "Art.scnassets/opening/aircraft.scn"

    //var uiOverlay = Overlay()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView.scene = SCNScene(named:"Art.scnassets/openingScene.scn")

        scene = sceneView.scene
        sceneView.isPlaying = true


        setupScene()
```

In setupScene() I try this to get the animation, but it returns nil:

```
//Get ALL available anims
func extractAnimationsFromSceneSource(sceneName: String) {
    if let sceneURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: sceneName, withExtension: "dae")
    {
        let source = SCNSceneSource(url: sceneURL, options: nil)

        var anims = [CAAnimation]()
        let animationsIDs = source?.identifiersOfEntries(withClass: CAAnimation.self) as! [String]
        for animationID in animationsIDs {
            if let animation = source?.entryWithIdentifier(animationID, withClass: CAAnimation.self) as? CAAnimation {
                anims.append(animation)
            }
        }
        print("FULL: ", anims)
    }
}
```

What is wrong here? I just want to play an animation unaltered from Blender, exactly as it is in Blender.